# Is there any trick to get vw resizing to work on the :before pseudoclass on webkit browsers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, webkit

There's a well-known bug when using vw sizes on webkit browsers where they don't update when the window is resized. The work-around hack has always been to use javascript to force a redraw of the element (usually just by reassigning the z-index) on resize. Like:

CSS:

```
#siteSearch input { font-size:10vw;}
```

Javascript/jQuery:

```
function resizing()  { $("#siteSearch *").css("z-index", 1) }
window.onresize=resizing;
```

But that doesn't seem to work on :before content. I made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FfJA3/1/) to demonstrate. If you resize the window, the search box/text changes size just fine, but the magnifying glass, which is an icon font character generated by :before content, does not. You have to refresh the page/re-run the JSFiddle to update that. If you try it in Firefox, the icon doesn't show properly because of the Firefox cross-site issue, but that's unrelated. The sizing works there.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it's really hard to make pseudo element do anything with javascript. I did try but could not solve it that way. So my suggestion is to wrap it all in a label element and add the glyficon in there and then style the label.

HTML

```
<div id="siteSearch">
    <label>&#xf002;<input type="text" placeholder="Search" /></label>
</div>
```

And the css

```
#siteSearch input {
    background-color:transparent;
    border: 0 none;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    color: #666;
    width:4em;
    padding: .3em .5em .3em .6em;
    font-size:10vw;
    border-radius: 1em;
}

#siteSearch label {
    position:relative;
    color: #666;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-size:10vw;
    left:1.6em;
    top:.1em;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:#ECF0FC;
    border-radius: 1em;
    padding-left:.5em;
}
```

I also ha a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FfJA3/2/) so u can try it.

I hope this will help u some any way and good luck!

Comment: I guess that works.  I originally only had an input, and then added the magnifying glass through input:before… but as it turns out, that only works with Safari.  So I reluctantly added in the #siteSearch container just to get it to work with all browsers.  I'd hate to add in yet another container just to get the resizing working reliably when a webkit user resizes their browser.  I guess I could do something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/FfJA3/4/), though that still requires adding in the glyficon in the content when I was hoping to keep it in the styles.

Comment: Someone else (outside of stack overflow) just suggested setting the :before font size to 100% and including the parent on the javascript bit, and that also seems to work.
http://jsfiddle.net/FfJA3/3/

Comment: Oh cool, then u can use 1em for font size on booth children and only update the z-index on the parent. Se the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FfJA3/5/)